# How can I 'unroll' a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
data = [['loc1', 1], ['loc2', 3], ['loc3', 3], ['loc4', 1], ['loc5',2], ['loc6',1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['loc', 'count'])
```

And I want to unroll/de-aggregate it, so that I have 1 row for loc1, 4 rows for loc2, 3 rows for loc3, etc. where each of those new rows has a unique and incrementing identifier associated with it.

Something like this:

```
data = [['loc1', 'id1'], ['loc2', 'id2'], ['loc2', 'id3'], ['loc2', 'id4'] , ['loc3', 'id5'], ['loc3', 'id6'], ['loc3', 'id7'], ['loc4', 'id8'], ['loc5', 'id9'], ['loc5', 'id10'], ['loc6', 'id11']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['loc', 'incrementingId'])
```

First, I imagine this is a somewhat common data manipulation to make, but I don't know what to call it.

Second, how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: much clearer on second look :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), create default index by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` and for new columns and then add new column by index values with `id` and adding `1`:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['count'])].reset_index(drop=True) 
df['incrementingId'] = 'id' + (df.index + 1).astype(str)
print (df)
     loc incrementingId
0   loc1            id1
1   loc2            id2
2   loc2            id3
3   loc2            id4
4   loc3            id5
5   loc3            id6
6   loc3            id7
7   loc4            id8
8   loc5            id9
9   loc5           id10
10  loc6           id11
```

Comment: on the second line, why is it 
df['incrementingId'] = df['incrementingId'] = 'id' + (df.index + 1).astype(str) instead of just df['incrementingId'] = 'id' + (df.index + 1).astype(str)?

Comment: @BradDavis - Yes, it is typo.

Comment: Okay, great :) I wasn't sure if it was a python trick I was unaware of.
Would it be that hard to reset the counter for incrementingId based on the change of a value in an additional column?  I didn't generalize the problem very well. I can updqte the question to better explain it